# How to run an RScript from local to remote server

Tags: r, remote-server

I have an rscript that is on my local desktop but I want to run this in a directory that is on a remote password protected sever. R is already installed in this computing cluster but what do I use in my terminal to execute the R script?

Thanks!

Comment: Do you want the script to run in the remote directory but on your local machine, or on the remote machine in the remote directory? What is the OS of your remote machine? How do you access it?

Comment: Can you copy your R script to the remote server?

Comment: Essentially, I want to run the script on the remote machine in the remote directory. The OS is Linux!

Comment: Also, I am not allowed to copy to the remote server, I don't have the authorisation to do that.